# Node Jquery load pages into div error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
// Userlist data array for filling in info box
var userListData = [];

// DOM Ready =============================================================
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Populate the user table on initial page load
    populateTable();
 
    // Username link click
    $('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkshowuser', showUserInfo);
 // Add User button click
    $('#btnAddUser').on('click', addUser);
 
    // Delete User link click
    $('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkdeleteuser', deleteUser);
  
  //Set Default page to Home.html
 $('#content').load('views/home.html');
 
 //Call navBar function
 navBar();
 projectBtn();

});


// Functions =============================================================
 
 //Navbar function
function navBar() {
 
 $('ul#navtest li a').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#content').fadeOut(400);
  setTimeout(function(){$('#content').load('views/' + page + '.html')}, 400);
  $('#content').fadeIn(400);
  return false;
 });
}

function projectBtn() {
 
 $('a.projectbutton').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#content').fadeOut(400);
  setTimeout(function(){$('#content').load('views/' + page + '.html')}, 400);
  $('#content').fadeIn(400);
  return false;
 });
}




// Fill table with data
function populateTable() {

    // Empty content string
    var tableContent = '';

    // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
    $.getJSON( '/users/userlist', function( data ) {

    // Stick our user data array into a userlist variable in the global object
    userListData = data;

        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
    });
};


// Show User Info
function showUserInfo(event) {

    // Prevent Link from Firing
    event.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve username from link rel attribute
    var thisUserName = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Get Index of object based on id value
    var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem.username; }).indexOf(thisUserName);

    // Get our User Object
    var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];

    //Populate Info Box
    $('#userInfoName').text(thisUserObject.fullname);
    $('#userInfoAge').text(thisUserObject.age);
    $('#userInfoGender').text(thisUserObject.gender);
    $('#userInfoLocation').text(thisUserObject.location);

};


// Add User
function addUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Super basic validation - increase errorCount variable if any fields are blank
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('#addUser input').each(function(index, val) {
        if($(this).val() === '') { errorCount++; }
    });

    // Check and make sure errorCount's still at zero
    if(errorCount === 0) {

        // If it is, compile all user info into one object
        var newUser = {
            'username': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
            'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
            'fullname': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(),
            'age': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserAge').val(),
            'location': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocation').val(),
            'gender': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserGender').val()
        }

        // Use AJAX to post the object to our adduser service
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newUser,
            url: '/users/adduser',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {

                // Clear the form inputs
                $('#addUser fieldset input').val('');

                // Update the table
                populateTable();

            }
            else {

                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // If errorCount is more than 0, error out
        alert('Please fill in all fields');
        return false;
    }
};


// Delete User
function deleteUser(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Pop up a confirmation dialog
    var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');

    // Check and make sure the user confirmed
    if (confirmation === true) {

        // If they did, do our delete
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/users/deleteuser/' + $(this).attr('rel')
        }).done(function( response ) {

            // Check for a successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {
            }
            else {
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
            }

            // Update the table
            populateTable();

        });

    }
    else {

        // If they said no to the confirm, do nothing
        return false;

    }

};
```

```css
.border {
  border: 4px solid black; }

.back2 {
  background-color: #232323; }

.marginleft {
  margin-left: 8%; }

.margin {
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%; }

.padding {
  padding: 1%; }

.margintop {
  margin-top: 1%; }

.margintop2 {
  margin-top: 5%; }

.iconmargintop {
  margin-top: 50px; }

.fill {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

p {
  color: #ffffff; }

label {
  color: #ffffff; }

h1 {
  color: #ffffff; }

h2 {
  color: #ffffff; }

th {
  color: #ffffff; }

span {
  color: #ffffff; }

h3 {
  color: #ffffff; }

.projectseltext {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%; }

.background {
  background-color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; }

#blacktext {
  color: black; }

.disablelink {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default; }

.nav {
  background-color: #b2b2b2; }

.nav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.nav li {
  display: inline; }

.back1 {
  background-color: #0c0c0c; }

.fit {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

.well {
  background-color: #333333; }

.backg1 {
  background-color: #333333; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="project">
      <div class="container-fluid row">
        <a href="#" title="projectnew" class="projectbutton">
          <div class="back2 col-md-11 margin border">
            <img src="images/ph.jpg" class="thumbnail margin col-md-3" style="width:150px;" />
            <h1 class="margin" style="margin-top:75px;">New Projects</h1>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
    <script src="build/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/js/global.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid nav navbar-inverse">
      <ul id="navtest" class="margintop">
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="home" id="blacktext">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="project" id="blacktext">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="contact" id="blacktext">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="resume" id="blacktext">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="about" id="blacktext">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="database" id="blacktext">Database</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='content' class="tab-content" />
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="projectnew">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container col-md-12 margintop marginleft">
          <a href="#project" data-toggle="tab">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid margin">
          <a href="" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="back2 col-md-11 margin border">
              <img src="images/ph.jpg" class="thumbnail margin" style="width:150px" />
              <h1 class="margin">Comming soon.</h1>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This file is temporary, i know the contents wont do anything.

The function navBar works perfectly, however when trying to apply the same method to another class and div it seems to fail.

Whenever i click on the projectbutton class it redirects to error.html. For some reason the javascript is not seeing/handling the class on click and the href being an unsupported type redirects me to error.html. However i'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

welcome;

In your HTML code, `<a href="projectnew" class="projectbutton">` you have an href for your a element, if you click on this, it will go to the page "www.yourdomain.com/projectnew" since this page does not exist, you will be redirected to your error page...

---

To solve this problem, you should use preventDefault, in order to prevent your link element to o**perate things that you do not want.**

```
    $('a.projectbutton').click(function(event)  {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').fadeOut(400);
        setTimeout(function(){$('#content').load('views/' + page + '.html')}, 400);
        $('#content').fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    });
```

I did not try it out, but it should work.

Read more about preventDefault: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

---

OR;

Since the main problem is your href attributes in your a elements, try to remove them;

```
<a href="#" title="home" id="blacktext">Home</a>
```

Use title as your specifier in your JS;

```
$('a.projectbutton').click(function()   {
    var page = $(this).attr('title'); //changed this into title.
    $('#content').fadeOut(400);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#content').load('views/' + page + '.html')}, 400);
    $('#content').fadeIn(400);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. I used the same method and when i click on  <ul id="navtest" class="margintop">
        <li>
          <a href="home" id="blacktext">Home</a>
</li>
etc..

It correctly takes the home from href and changes #content to be filled with views/home.html

The projects one does not seem to add views or html from what i can see.

Comment: It works for the nav bar but the projectbutton does nothing now. May it have something to do with the project html not being loaded until it is passed to index? idk.

Comment: Well... did you do the same thing as; 
        `<a title="projectnew" href="#" class="projectbutton">` and also in your js?

Comment: the function:      

function projectBtn() {
 
 $('a.projectbutton').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#content').fadeOut(400);
  setTimeout(function(){$('#content').load('views/' + page + '.html')}, 400);
  $('#content').fadeIn(400);
  return false;
 });
}


the html:      

 <a href="#" title="projectnew" class="projectbutton">
          <div class="back2 col-md-11 margin border">
          </div>
        </a>

Comment: Do you actually have the projectnew.html file in your views/ ?

Comment: Yes, and it is formatted correctly. Thank you for helping btw.

Comment: Can you edit the question as the current state of your code?

Comment: It is so hard to see the problem like this... Sorry, can you upload your project to a live server?

Comment: Sure its gonna take some time to ftp transfer it to my webserver though one moment.

Comment: This will take a while, ill update when its done tomorrow.

Comment: Just add me in mention when you do, so I can check.

Comment: Burak Tokak, i have deployed the site at www.austinwgary.com

Comment: Sadly, I'm unable to see the content of the site. I'm thinking there is a problem with your DNS?

Comment: Actually, i think i figured it out, the javascript is loaded on index document ready but the html for the project page is not loaded into the page so its not applied.